# Collection of objects that are set up only if actually used

Tags: python-3.x, class, collections

I'm writing a class to manage a collection of objects that I'd like to "load" only if actually used (immagine that each object is an heavy document). Also I want to refer to each object both with a numeric key and a string name.
I decided to create a class that inherits from OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class MyClass:
    def load_me(self, key):
        print(f"Object {key} loaded")

class MyClassColl(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):

        if isinstance(key, int):
            key = list(self.keys())[key]

        res = super().get(key).load_me(key)
        return res
```

When I initialise the collection and retrieve a single object everything works well and:

```
my_coll = MyClassColl([('Obj1', MyClass()), ('Obj2', MyClass()), ('Obj3', MyClass())])

my_obj = my_coll['Obj2']     # or my_obj = my_coll[1]
```

prints:

```
Object Obj2 loaded
```

But using a loop, the objects are not properly loaded so:

```
for key, item in my_coll.items():
    obj = item
```

has not output.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `__getitem__` method is not getting called when you loop through the dictionary like that. It is only called when you use an index operator (as far as I know). So, a super easy fix would be to do your `for` loop like this:

```
for key in my_coll:
    item = my_coll[key]
```

Alternatively you could try playing around with the `__iter__` method but I think the way you've done it is probably ideal.